# Apache Wicket: Respond with generated File without DownloadLink

Tags: download, request, wicket, response

I do have a form where the user can put in an ID. When the form is submitted the application should direct respond with a file download. The tricky spot is: instead of a downloadlink I need a direct file repsonse, so the users don't have to click a downloadlink. The site shouldn't change so the user can immediately put another ID into the form and can fire the next form-submit for download. How do I respond in the onSubmit()-Method of my form and keep the site displayed?

Is there a standard solution or pattern I can use with Wicket? Do you have any examples?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect this isn't really feasible because one HTTP request can only (normally) be followed by one response, and that should be either the form page or the download. What you can probably do however is to respond with the form page but with a Javascript in the page triggering the download itself.

Comment: Can't understand why don't use ajax? Implement AJAXDownload and set  AjaxButton as a submit button of the form. It won't response to another page and allow you to dinamicly change files to download according to form input. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do I really need Ajax? If I use pure Java-Servlets I only use servletResponse.getOutputStream() and write the file directly into the response. The original site is kept. How do I do that with Wicket?

Comment: Then you don't need any Wicket components. Just create and register in web.xml new Servlet,which will handle response, and set action in form markup according to Servlet mapping and method=post. You still can use wicket form, for some reason. As for me, ajax is an option, which allows you not to worry about servlets, process some additional actions (update some components, for example) while download initiating and stay at current page.

Answer (score 4):

This will be a long post

Ok, I will post two solutions - with and without ajax. If I understand you correctly, you want to submit form with one parameter and initiate file downloading, remaining on the same page to be able to input different parameter and submit form again.

***Request/Response handling (no Ajax).***

In my comments I suggest you to use another servlet, but you can avoid this, by handling form `onSubmit` method. I will assume that you know how to set outputStream for response and will hide this implementation.

First, you have a page or a panel with a form **in java**:

```java
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    /*input text of the input field. (your ID).*/
    private String input;

    ....

    /*initialization method, called from constructor(or place this in constructor).*/
    private void init()
    {
        /*Form with overrided onSubmit method. Has Void generic, because doesn't map any object as a model.*/
        Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form")
        {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit() {

                /*This is the case. You can get request and response from RequestCycle, but you have to cast them (response at least) to WebRequest/WebResponse, to access required methods.*/
                /*----------------------------------------------------*/
                WebRequest req = (WebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
                WebResponse resp = (WebResponse)RequestCycle.get().getResponse();

                /* Get request parameter. Id of the parameter is equals to text field id. Also you can check to null or emptyness of the parameter here. */
                String idParameter = req.getPostParameters().getParameterValue("input").toString();

                ...

                /* Creating file or your implementation of the stream */
                File file = ...;

                /* Use proper content type for each file. */
                resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
                resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                resp.setContentLength((int) file.length());

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = ...
                ...
                /* Write file to response */
                while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
                }
                ...
                /*That's all.*/
            }
        };

        /* Add TextField to form and set PropertyModel for this field.*/
        form.add(new TextField<String>("input", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "input")));
        /* Don't forget to add form itself */
        add ( form );
    }
}
```

**in html**:

```html
    ...
    <!-- You can also specify target="_blank" parameter for form-->
    <form wicket:id="form">
        <input type="text" wicket:id="input" />
    </form>
    ...
```

You even don't need submit button, and can press Enter after text input. That's all.

***Ajax handling.***

First of all, you need to implement AJAXDownload class. It is very common class and I wonder why it does not included in a standart wicket libraries. It's implementation you can look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow). There is no much code.

Ok, and now, using same page class, just update init method **in java**:

```java
private void init() {
        final AJAXDownload download = new AJAXDownload() {
            @Override
            protected IResourceStream getResourceStream() {

                /*Implementing resource according to input ID*/
                return createResourceStream(input);
            }
        };
        add ( download );

        /*Now, we don't override form, but use AjaxButton instead*/
        Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");
        form.add(new TextField<String>("input", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "input")));

        /*Every button has onSubmit method. And AjaxButton has it's implementation with AjaxRequestTarget instance, which allows to update any component via ajax.*/
        form.add(new AjaxButton("submit", Model.of("Submit"), form) {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

                /*Initiate download according to AJAXDownload api*/
                download.initiate(target);
            }
        });
        add(form);
    }

    /*Method to implement wicket IResourceStream*/
    private IResourceStream createResourceStream(String input) {
        return new FileResourceStream(new File(...));
    }
```

Note that you can also override `getFileName` method of the `AJAXDownload` class.

*Update*. Forgot to add **html** changes:

```html
<form wicket:id="form">
   <input type="text" wicket:id="input" />
   <input type="submit" wicket:id="submit" />
</form>
```

I have tested every implementation via Wicket 6.17 and it's working. Hope it will help you.

And tell me if this is not what you want to achive.

Comment: You are right, I want to stay always on the same page to initiate one file download after another. By the way I already realized your non-ajax-approach but I get this errormessage after onSubmit().

"ERROR - DefaultExceptionMapper     - Unexpected error occurred
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response"

Why? I only called webResponse.getOutputStream() once.

Comment: It could happen if you call HttpServletResponse.getWriter() somewhere too. See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.java#ServletResponse.getOutputStream%28%29 javadoc